# Looking for ALL of the Rambam's Books in English on Medicine

Tags: product-recommendation, rambam, medicine, english

Looking for ALL of the Rambam's Books in English on Medicine

Preferably in Eretz Yisrael, without breaking the bank.

How many books are there? What are the most prominent in which he discusses formulas and exact remedies?

Trusted translations only. Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, JSarai, and thanks for the question :) ...Are you asking about the Rambam's writings on *medical halacha* or on *medicine*? The former is definitely on topic here, while the latter may or may not be (I am not certain). Note also that the Rambam would likely advise you to not take his advice practically today, favoring instead what modern science teaches. Anyway, I hope you find a satisfying answer to your query :)

Comment: Once I have your attention; you may want to check out our [beginner's guide to the site](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and/or the short [tour]. I hope to see you around! :)

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your question slightly -- you can see the revision history [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/82638/revisions), and you can also [edit] your post in case I did anything that wasn't to your liking. ...you mention translations in the post; I assumed you meant English translations, but I wasn't sure. If that was your intent, you can add the [tag:english] tag to your post.

Answer (score 2):

[Goodreads.com's Maimoninides pages](https://www.goodreads.com/author/list/194459.Maimonides) have a bunch of Rambam's books on medicine(a dozen of them), as well as everything else. Just click on the titles of the ones you want, and then use the "Get a copy" links.  One of them, his "Regimen on Health" treatise, is only available on Kindle, but the rest of them are available in print copies. One of his most famous works is his series of treatises collected and published as "Medical Aphorisms", which are his compilations of information from Galen and other ancient medical authorities, some lost except for Maimonides' extracts of them. Its five volumes are available, except for the last one which will be published next month.  I don't know the size of the straw that will break your bank's back, but most of his works are less than $100US - the exceptions being long out-of-print items.

Comment: Congratulations on 1,000 points, Gary! May you continue [from strength to strength](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9705/5323) :)

Comment: @Shokhet - Thank you!  Four years + of fun in the shark tank!